# can we capture data that comes to a browser from a website?

Tags: python, web-services, networking, browser, web

i am not sure whether we can capture data from website i.e. suppose if we submit a form we get some data in response from website. How can we capture that data ?.

for example consider a college results website if we enter roll number it gives results data in a browser.i want to know how we can capture and store that data to a database using a program instead of showing it on browser?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an entirely Python framework: using [Mechanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/) as a browser and form filler, and an html parser like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to extract and then store the various information you get. To store your results in a database you could then use SQLite.

Comment: Not as far as I know, only for Python 2.7

Comment: @hedi, is there any equivalent to mechanize for python 3.x

Comment: @wudpecker Try [this](https://github.com/adevore/mechanize/tree/python3) experimental github.

Comment: thank you @heidi, i stored results data using mechanize, beautiful Soup and python 2.7.6. These things helped me to get what i want. Thanks once again :)